# Rotating cubes to face the origin using Quaternions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I'm in the process of setting up a relatively simple voxel-based world for a game. The high level idea is to first generate voxel locations following a fibonacci grid, then rotate the cubes such that the outer surface of the fibonacci grid resembles a sphere, and finally size the cubes such that they roughly cover the surface of the sphere (overlap is fine). See below the code for generating the voxels along the fibonacci grid:

```
    public static Voxel[] CreateInitialVoxels(int numberOfPoints, int radius)
    {
        float goldenRatio = (1 + Mathf.Sqrt(5)) / 2;
        Voxel[] voxels = new Voxel[numberOfPoints];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
        {
            float n = i - numberOfPoints / 2;  // Center at zero
            float theta = 2 * Mathf.PI * n / goldenRatio;
            float phi = (Mathf.PI / 2) + Mathf.Asin(2 * n / numberOfPoints);
            voxels[i] = new Voxel(new Location(theta, phi, radius));
        }
        return voxels;
    }
```

This generates a sphere that looks roughly like a staircase

[image]

So, my current approach to get this looking a bit more spherical is to basically rotate each cube in each pair of axes, then combine all of the rotations:

```
private void DrawVoxel(Voxel voxel, GameObject voxelContainer)
{
    GameObject voxelObject = Instantiate<GameObject>(GetVoxelPrefab());

    voxelObject.transform.position = voxel.location.cartesianCoordinates;
    voxelObject.transform.parent = voxelContainer.transform;

    Vector3 norm = voxel.location.cartesianCoordinates.normalized;

    float xyRotationDegree = Mathf.Atan(norm.y / norm.x) * (180 / Mathf.PI);
    float zxRotationDegree = Mathf.Atan(norm.z / norm.x) * (180 / Mathf.PI);
    float yzRotationDegree = Mathf.Atan(norm.z / norm.y) * (180 / Mathf.PI);

    Quaternion xyRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(xyRotationDegree, new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
    Quaternion zxRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(zxRotationDegree, new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    Quaternion yzRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(yzRotationDegree, new Vector3(1, 0, 0));

    voxelObject.transform.rotation = zxRotation * yzRotation * xyRotation;
}
```

The primary thing that I am getting caught on is that each of these rotations seems to work fine for me in isolation, but when combining them things tend to go a bit haywire (pictures below) I'm not sure exactly what the issue is. My best guess is that I've made some sign/rotation mismatch in my rotations so they don't combine right. I can get two working, but never all three together.

[image: Success in One Axis]
[image: View From third axis when two rotations have been successfully applied]
[image: Standard Failure Mode when attempting to combine third rotation]

Above are the pictures of one and two successful rotations, followed by the error mode when I attempt to combine them. Any help either on telling me that the approach I'm following is too convoluted, or helping me understand what the right way to combine these rotations would be would be very helpful. Cartesian coordinate conversion below for reference.

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct Location
{
    public float theta, phi, r;
    public Vector3 polarCoordinates;

    public float x, y, z;
    public Vector3 cartesianCoordinates;

    public Location(float theta, float phi, float r)
    {
        this.theta = theta;
        this.phi = phi;
        this.r= r;
        this.polarCoordinates = new Vector3(theta, phi, r);

        this.x = r * Mathf.Sin(phi) * Mathf.Cos(theta);
        this.y = r * Mathf.Sin(phi) * Mathf.Sin(theta);
        this.z = r * Mathf.Cos(phi);
        this.cartesianCoordinates = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this problem, though it's still not clear to me what the issue with the above code is.

Unity has an extremely handy function called `Quaternion.FromToRotation` that will generate the appropriate rotation if you simply pass in the appropriate destination vector.

In my case I was able to just do:
`voxelObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), voxel.location.cartesianCoordinates);`